# Одновременно работающий код js и jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Написал код слайдера на `javascript` и мне понадобилась функция клонирования из `jquery`.
Как заставить их работать вместе без проблем?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    blockLeft = document.getElementById("forBlockBigLeft");
    mainImg = document.getElementById("main1");
    a1 = document.getElementsByClassName("a");
    img1 = [
        "images/11.jpg", "images/12.jpg", "images/13.jpg", "images/14.jpg",
        "images/5.jpg", "images/6.jpg", "images/7.jpg", "images/8.jpg",
        "images/9.jpg", "images/10.jpg", "images/11.jpg"
    ];

    function slide_img() {
        for(i=0; i<a1.length; i++) {
            a1[i].innerHTML = 
            "<img src="+img1[i]+" width='img.naturalWidth' height='150px'>";
        }
    }

    function right() {
        l = img1.shift();
        img1.push(l);
        slide_img();
    }

    function left() {
        r = img1.pop();
        img1.unshift(r);
        slide_img();
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#main1").clone().appendto("#forBlockBigLeft");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: судя по коду: код на яваскрипте и с использованием jQuery не пересекаются

Comment: main1  это идентификатор второго дива,  а всем дивам ещё и задан класс   


           a1 = document.getElementsByClassName("a");

Comment: Весь «код js » переносите в `$(document).ready` иначе на момент запуска «кода жиэс» дерево dom может просто не существовать.

Comment: @ReinRaus, без знания _где_ расположен текущий тег скрипт совет преждевременный

Comment: пробовал, выдаёт ошибку ---  Uncaught ReferenceError: left is not defined

Comment: @Grundy в приведенном коде это единственное, что может вызывать проблему (считая, что код корректен и способен выполнить то, что должен)

Comment: расположено в нижней части  кода html

Comment: @ReinRaus, в любом случае без воспроизводимого примера ничего сказать нельзя

Comment: @Тигран вынесите объявления функций за пределы «документ.реади». А вообще, удобнее навешивать события, а не хардкодить в html разметке

Comment: функция написанная на  javascript работает валидно

Comment: @Grundy есть вероятность 99%, что я прав ;-)

Comment: но ведь функции у меня не находятся внутри    $(document).ready(function() 
или я что то не понял ?

Comment: могу вам рассказать секрет. jQuery это и есть javascript, просто он является кроссбраузерной библиотекой с набором удобных методов

Comment: Кусок `blockLeft = document.getElementById("forBlockBigLeft");
    mainImg = document.getElementById("main1");
    a1 = document.getElementsByClassName("a");
    img1 = [
        "images/11.jpg", "images/12.jpg", "images/13.jpg", "images/14.jpg",
        "images/5.jpg", "images/6.jpg", "images/7.jpg", "images/8.jpg",
        "images/9.jpg", "images/10.jpg", "images/11.jpg"
    ];` перенести в документ.риди. Только его. Объявления функций оставить вне документ.риди

Comment: я это знаю , но с ними у меня возникают проблемы , это от недостатка опыта , со временем пройдет полагаю

Comment: не выдало ошибки , сработало , но функция  клонирования почему то  не сработала

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть стоит использовать elem.cloneNode(true) вместо JQ?
Например так:

```
"use strict";

 var main1 = document.querySelector("#main1");  
 var forBlockBigLeft = document.querySelector("#forBlockBigLeft");

 var new_elem = main1.cloneNode(true);
 main1.parentNode.insertBefore(new_elem, forBlockBigLeft.nextSibling);
```

Comment: премного благодарен , я совсем  забыл про это